# Show most recent deployment or rerun, like in the classic release UI

Tags: azure-pipelines, pipeline, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

When moving from the DevOps Releases way of deploying our applications to a YAML format, we noticed that we have no way of actually knowing the currently running release. We can see the most recently run pipeline, but if someone reruns a stage in an older pipeline it wouldn't be visisble in the list of pipelines. Contrary to the classic Release way of doing it, we could actually see the release that is running.

This image shows how the pipeline is displayed in the list of runs now:
[Screen capture of what it looks like in Pipelines with YAML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gg4W2.png)

This is the old way:
[Screen capture of what it looks like in the old Releases way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5o8PT.png)

In the second image (Releases) it's much clearer to see what is most recently deployed. **Since it highlights the stages that have been run most recently**. Even though the Release in the top also has completed the stages to Dev and Testing, it shows that the second Release is the one that's actually running on the respective environments. One could think that this isn't an issue since Pipelines always display in the most recent run order, **but if you rerun a stage in a previous pipeline run, it won't move that run to the top.** (Hence making it impossible to see from a glance what deployment is currently running)

Is this possible to achieve in some way using YAML pipelines in DevOps?

Answer (score 0):

In the yaml pipelines you have the concept of [Environments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/environments?view=azure-devops). In your yaml release pipeline, you can use the [deployment job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/environments?view=azure-devops#target-an-environment-from-a-deployment-job) and target a particular environment in each of the stages: dev, test, etc.

If you like to know which pipeline run has been recently deployed to a particular environment you can just open [deployment history](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/environments?view=azure-devops#deployment-history) section of the environment.

You can design the environments in many ways for example single environment per all applications like dev, test, then you have a single overview of recently deployed applications on a particular environment.

OR

You can granulate environments and create a dedicated per each application something like App1-dev, App2-dev, App1-test, App2-test, etc.